# Java: Merging two JSON objects without iterating

Tags: java, json

I have two JSON objects like

```
{  
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3",
   "key4":"value4"
}
```

and

```
{
   "key2":"value1",
   "key4":"value2",
   "key6":"value3",
   "key8":"value4"
}
```

I want to merge these two JSON objects into single `Json` object without iterating through each key and the final result should be

```
{
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value1",
   "key3":"value3",
   "key4":"value2",
   "key6":"value3",
   "key8":"value4"
}
```

Comment: what the final outcome you are expecting ?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any Json Mapper (e.g Jackson) convert json to Map.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){})
```

once you get two maps like this you can merge them

```
Map<String, Object> mergedMap = new HashMap<>();
mergedMap.putAll(map1);
mergedMap.putAll(map2);
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(mergedMap);
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it without converting to map

Comment: There is no other way. This is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library that does this job for you, like [JSON Merge](https://github.com/oswaldobapvicjr/jsonmerge/), available at Maven Central.

You will get the desired result with a single line of code:

```
JSONObject result = new JsonMerger<>(JSONObject.class).merge(json2, json1);
```

**Note:** the first JSON parameter passed to the `merge` method will always have more precedence/importance than the second one in case of key collisions.

This library works with Jackson, Gson, and other JSON providers as well.